# Pourquoi l'usage de l'esperluette a-t-il disparu ?

Tags: histoire, typographie, ligatures

On trouve dans la langue française écrite jusqu'aux environs du dix-neuvième siècle la ligature *&*, appelée esperluette. D'après [Wikipédia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Esperluette#cite_note-L79-0), elle est aujourd'hui rejetée dans la langue littéraire. Quelle est l'origine de ce changement?

Au passage, un [google ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com) pour visualiser le phénomène:

[image: occurences comparatives de & et et]

Il semble que le changement se produise aux alentours de 1780.

Au passage, merci [F'x](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/19/fx) pour l'idée du ngram.

Comment: A priori pour la même raison que les autres ligatures esthétiques (pas toujours évidentes à lire), non?

Comment: L'usage de l'esperlu&te aurait &é abandonné ? Par qui ?

Comment: En étudiant l'origine de ces ligatures, n'y verrait-on pas un élément de réponse? Par exemple, si ces symboles ont été apportés dans un souci d'économie d'encre ou de temps de copie, il pourrait sembler logique que leur usage diminue dès que la copie demande moins de temps et d'encre.

Comment: @Joubarc: théoriquement, la plupart des ligatures sont censées *améliorer* la lisibilité ('ii'→'ij'→'y' est un bon exemple)... Mais la notion même de lisibilité est quelque peu subjective...

Comment: @dave, le y comme ligature... ça me semble étrange. J'aimerais une référence. (On utilise en néérlandais une ligature ij et certains la remplacent parfois par un ÿ dans les fontes ou les codages qui n'en disposent pas, mais c'est un usage impropre.)

Comment: En passant (mais pas source d'une réponse si j'ai bonne mémoire) [Nœuds & esperluettes Actualité et pérennité d’un signe, Cahier Gutenberg n°22](http://cahiers.gutenberg.eu.org/cg-bin/article/CG_1995___22_43_0.pdf)

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Tout simplement: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(typographie) :-)

Comment: @Dave, Wikipedia sans références ne m'en semble pas une, j'y ai trop vu d'erreurs :) j'avoue sans les corriger :(  Y. Perrousseaux dans son _Histoire de l'écriture typographie_ donne des facsimilé de vieux caractères typographique (p.e. celui de la Sorbonne vers 1470 p. 124) sans j mais avec un y, et le y est dans les lettres, pas avec les ligatures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

J'ai trouvé un [article](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/ipb/index.php?act=ST&f=2&t=4978) intéressant sur ce sujet. Comme il se situe dans un forum, je me permets de citer entièrement la réponse car elle peut être amenée à disparaître.

> Il est difficile de déterminer précisément une date de disparition du
>   S en forme de F (ou S long) et de l’esperluette (ou de la perluette)
>   en imprimerie. L’esperluette est à l’origine une ligature,
>   c'est-à-dire l’union de deux lettres en un seul signe, ici les deux
>   lettres de *et*. Les Anglais la réservaient à la liaison de deux noms
>   propres alors que les Français ont cru longtemps économiser de l’encre
>   en l’utilisant systématiquement à la place de *et* avant de la délaisser
>   au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle.
>
> **C'est à la suite des travaux du typographe italien Giambattista Bodoni
>   (1730–1813) et surtout de la famille des typographes et imprimeurs
>   français Didot (François-Ambroise « l’aîné » et surtout
>   Pierre-François « le jeune ») qu’une nouvelle typographie s’est
>   imposée abandonnant certains archaïsmes.** Cette typographie stricte et
>   logique élaborée dans la période 1785–1801, s’est affirmée pendant la
>   période impériale qui correspondait bien à une réforme dans tous les
>   domaines. Elle sera diffusée largement dans toute l’Europe par le
>   biais d’ouvrages des grands auteurs classiques (Racine, Boileau, La
>   Fontaine), de livres de fêtes (Sacre de Napoléon) et surtout du Code
>   civil. Mais malgré tout, elle ne fait que confirmer les tendances
>   novatrices en gestation depuis la fin du XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle. En 1806, dans
>   « L’Art du typographe », (p.17) Vinçard indique que les doubles
>   lettres (dont le double S long) et l’esperluette « ont été supprimées
>   depuis les nouvelles gravures », ce qui est une référence évidente à
>   Didot.
>
> **On peut donc situer l’abandon de l’utilisation en imprimerie du S long
>   et de l’esperluette à la période du Directoire et du début du 1er
>   Empire. Cependant, en province, des imprimeurs ont fait perdurer les
>   habitudes de l’ancien régime plus tardivement.**
>
> Le S long a disparu, **mais pour les travaux de luxe la tradition de
>   l’esperluette a perduré.** Elle fut utilisée régulièrement dans les
>   impressions de luxe du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, ainsi pour les caractères « augustaux »
>   du lyonnais Louis Perrin. Elle est parfois employée de nos
>   jours dans certains ouvrages de bibliophilie.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que cette remarque dans l'article cité de [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperluette) explique en grande partie la cause :

> Son utilisation en français est essentiellement circonscrite à un usage commercial et publicitaire, pour les raisons sociales. L’esperluette est ainsi parfois appelée « et commercial ».

L'esperluette est aujourd'hui plus considérée comme une illustration qu'un caractère à part entière. De plus le caractère commercial lui confère une connotation péjorative qui ne doit pas être étranger à son déclin.

Comment: Oui, mais comment en est-on arrivé là? Son usage était courant dans les livres au 16e siècle par exemple.

Comment: @Raphink c'est bien le sens de ma question en effet

Comment: @Evpok A mon avis, juste parce que c'est assez ardu à faire à la main ! "A l'époque", ils prenaient le temps d'écrire, et bien (calligraphiquement parlant), alors qu'aujourd'hui, quand j'essaies d'en faire un joli à la main, il faut que je m'y reprenne à 10 fois pour arriver à quelque chose de potable.

Comment: @LudoMC Pas trop difficile pour les anglais; peut-etre que vous avez difficulté à écrire parce que vous ne pratiquez pas beaucoup?

Comment: @raphink hélas je n'ai pas de sources pour étayer mes propos. Je ne propose qu'une hypothèse qui me paraît très probable. Peut-être quelques linguistes savent cela, mais je n'ai pas trouver d'article sur le sujet dans mes brèves recherches.

Comment: @LudoMC: l'usage des abréviations dans les textes a perduré après l'apparition de l'imprimerie. J'ai ici http://r.pinson.free.fr/calvary/pdf/geneve_1564.pdf un exemple de reproduction d'une Bible du 16e siècle imprimée truffée d'abréviations (et pas seulement des &). Cela dit, j'ai l'impression que la compacité du texte jouait également un rôle important dans le choix de ces abréviations.

Comment: Ardu à faire : je n'ai jamais eu de mal à le tracer, mais en effet, j'ai vu beaucoup de gens bidouiller, souvent simplifiant en ne gardant que la partie basse, résultant en un alpha ɑ

Answer (score 2):

Je ne dirais pas que son usage a disparu, j'en vois encore, mais effectivement son usage est moins répandu, et n'est pas utilisé dans une phrase. Je pense que c'est parce que c'est une forme d'abréviation, et dans une phrase littéraire, on évite les abréviations. Cela rejoint un peu la question [Utilisation de la barre oblique (slash) pour une alternative](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/472/utilisation-de-la-barre-oblique-slash-pour-une-alternative) : elle est peu utilisée en littérature car c'est une forme d'abréviation.