# Utilisation de la barre oblique (slash) pour une alternative

Tags: ponctuation

L'utilisation du *slash* semble être [réservée aux barres de fractions](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponctuation) en français.

À quel point est-ce acceptable d'utiliser deux mots/expressions séparés par un *slash* en français ?

Parmi les autres possibilités dans ce cas précis :

- … deux mots (expressions) séparé(e)s par …
- … deux mots ou deux expressions séparés par …
- … deux mots, ou expressions, séparés par …

Par ailleurs, je ne suis pas sûr de savoir comment l'accord se fait dans le cas du *slash* et dans le dernier cas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C'est une question de style d'écriture. La barre oblique (qu'elle soit *slash* ou *backslash*) ne fait pas partie de la typographie standard en français (ni, à ma connaissance, dans aucune langue européenne). **La plupart des guides de style recommandent donc de ne pas l'utiliser**, et de préférer des construction plus longues mais plus claires. Néanmoins l'usage du slash, notamment dans composés comme « et/ou » devient répandu, notamment dans l'écriture informelle (mail, blog, …).

Je note une particularité de l'écriture technique et scientifique : dans ces domaines, les éditeurs sont particulièrement véhéments à enrayer l'usage croissant de l'oblique. Celle-ci diminue la clarté des propos et affaiblit donc le raisonnement que le texte doit éclairer.

Enfin, on note qu'il n'est pas (à ma connaissance) courant de **prononcer** cette oblique, alors que c'est fait couramment en anglais (y compris aux actualités) : *“the high energy physicist slash banjo player”*.

---

Par ailleurs, comme il n'y a je crois pas de différence majeure entre les usages français et anglais sur la question, on peut noter le lien vers la question correspondante sur *[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9044/avoid-the-slash)*.

Comment: La barre oblique est utilisée dans certaines abréviations, surtout sur et sous : s/ et /s essentiellement sur les panneaux de signalisation (je n'aime pas l'usage de s/s pour sous, je trouve la première forme plus visuelle...).

Comment: @Fx And the [quantum physicist slash bongo player](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Richard_Feynman)?

Comment: @Evpok this is where the idea for the example came from, but I tweaked it a bit :)

Answer (score 3):

À quel point?  Tout dépend de ton public. Personnellement, c'est une structure que je n'aime pas et que j'évite (c'est pour moi une abréviation et je ne m'en sert que quand je m'autorise des abréviations), et je ne suis pas parmi les plus puristes.

Quant à l'accord, je la comprends et la prononce comme un « ou », j'accorderais donc de même.

Answer (score 3):

La barre oblique (*slash*) n'est traditionnellement pas utilisée en typographie générale. On peut la rencontrer dans des abréviations (en prise de note, par exemple), ou dans des notations techniques. On la trouve dans des écrits informels tels que le courriel ou le clavardage, mais beaucoup plus rarement qu'en anglais (source : impression personnelle).

On peut très bien dire « deux mots ou expressions séparés par une barre oblique » ou « deux mots ou deux expressions séparés par une barre oblique ». L'accord est au masculin puisque l'une des possibilités est masculine. Quand à l'accord en nombre, il est ici forcément pluriel, mais dans le cas d'alternatives singulières, il est bien connu que [l'un ou l'autre se dit ou se disent](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominique_Bouhours#cite_note-0).

J'éviterais « deux mots, ou expressions, séparés [...] ». Ce n'est pas incorrect, mais c'est ambigü : ça pourrait vouloir dire que « expressions » est une manière de reformuler « mots » et non une alternative.

Comment: +1 pour les infos qui confirment/corroborent mon ressenti. Cela dit, j'eus préféré rester dans l'ignorance du mot « clavardage » :-)

Answer (score 2):

Personnellement, j'essaie de limiter l'usage du slash en français. Cela dit, il m'arrive de l'utiliser pour "et/ou", dans un contexte informel :

> La sécurité sociale doit prendre soin des personnes âgées et/ou malades.

Comment: Dans cet exemple, je pense qu'on peut parfaitement dire _La sécurité sociale doit prendre soin des personnes âgées et des malades_. On pourrait ergoter que c'est ambigu, mais il faudrait être de mauvaise foi. Pour moi, c'est un raccourci pour _La sécurité sociale doit prendre soin des personnes âgées et elle doit prendre soin des malades_. Mais j'ergote moi-même.

Comment: Il est possible que mon exemple soit mal choisi ;-)

Comment: Pas forcément, c'est vrai que "et/ou" est un bon exemple où tu peux difficilement remplacer la barre oblique par "et" ou "ou". Ce qui est bien dommage... _La sécurité sociale doit prendre soin des personnes âgées et ou ou malades_ aurait un certain charme. Bah, tant que personne ne propose de remplacer "/" par "et/ou", tout va bien.

Comment: @Joubarc: Tiens, perso, je comprend le « et » comme « elle doit prendre soin des personnes (agées et malades) », ce qui restreint l'ensemble des personnes. Avec un « ou » je comprends de la même façon : « elle doit prendre soin des personnes (agées ou malades) » ; et c'est sémantiquement la même chose que « (elle doit prendre soin des personnes âgées) *et* (elle doit prendre soin des personnes malades) ». Peut-être suis-je trop mathématicien ? En tout cas ce n'est pas un bon exemple pour expliquer l'ambiguité du *ou* (inclusif ou exclusif).

Comment: Exactement, c'est un problème de ou inclusif ou exclusif.

Comment: @Stéphane Oui, en fait j'ai (involontairement) rajouté l'article _des_ devant _malades_, ce qui a un peu changé le sens. En disant _... doit prendre soin des personnes âgées et **des** malades_, on lève en fait l'ambiguïté parce que _... doit prendre soin des personnes (âgées et des malades)_ ne marcherait pas. Mais sans l'article, je reconnais que c'est ambigu. (Ergotément ambigu, mais ambigu quand même.)

Comment: @Joubarc: Ah, mais tu avais changé la phrase en « des … et des … » ! Dans ce cas, oui, on comprend tous la même chose, et ça évite le *et/ou*. Par contre, il doit y avoir d'autres exemples où l'ambiguité apparaît, et où elle est plus difficile à contourner.

Comment: Mea culpa (http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/283/latin-phrases-used-in-french-too). J'espérais un peu que personne ne le remarque. (Ou alors, je pourrais prétendre que c'est voulu pour proposer une alternative au "et/ou" hideux.)

Comment: À mon oreille, il y a une ambiguïté dans « des personnes âgées et malades » qui peut être compris comme « des malades âgés » ou comme une ellipse pour « des personnes âgées et des personnes malades » (qui n'est pas ambigu tout comme « la SPA s'occupe des chiens et des chats » ne l'est pas), mais il n'y en a aucune dans « des personnes âgées ou malades » (si je veut une exclusion, je vais dire « soit des personnes âgées, soit des personnes malades » ou « ou des personnes âgées, ou des personnes malades » -- le « ou » initial marquant l'exclusion).

Answer (score 0):

Concernant de l'emploi abusif en français de l'anglicisme "et/ou" , c'est tout simplement oublier que le "ou" français peut autant avoir autant une valeur exclusive qu'inclusive si les deux termes reliés sont proches.  Cf. le très bon article à sujet sur Wiktionnaire : "http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ou"

De manière générale, hormis le fait que ce soit une importation anglo-saxonne, l'usage de la barre oblique, en dehors des contextes scientifique et informatique, est contestable car il révèle une pauvreté du lexique de rédacteur. 
La barre oblique remplit le rôle d'une préposition reliant deux mots : il suffit juste de se creuser la tête et de trouver la bonne !