# Comment indiquer qu'un « ou » est inclusif?

Tags: usage, conjonctions, coordination

Le « ou » en français n'est pas le « ou » de la logique. Il est parfois inclusif (un centre accueillant les personnes malades ou âgées ne va vraisemblablement pas refuser un vieillard malade) et parfois exclusif (le restaurateur vous proposant une formule avec entrée ou dessert ne va vraisemblablement pas vous permettre de prendre les deux).  En passant, le « et » a parfois une valeur plus proche de celle du « ou » de la logique (un refuge de la SPA accueillant chiens et chats ne va pas vous jeter si vous n'y amenez qu'un animal et si vous prenez un menu avec « fromage et dessert », le restaurateur ne va pas vous en vouloir si vous ne prenez pas de fromage).

Le contexte suffit **souvent** à indiquer quel est le sens voulu et il est assez facile de marquer sans ambiguïté et sans lourdeur que l'on désire un « ou » exclusif par l'utilisation de formules comme « tu prends *ou* la glace *ou* la tarte », « tu prends *soit* la glace *soit* la tarte », « tu prends *au choix* la glace *ou* la tarte ».

Mais à part l'horrible « et/ou » qu'on rencontre parfois, je ne vois pas de moyen simple de lever l'ambiguïté dans l'autre sens et le fait que « ou » soit normalement considéré comme inclusif ne convient pas toujours.

Quelles sont vos propositions ?  En particulier pour plus de deux choix (ajouter « ou les deux » est un peu lourd mais convient quand même assez bien pour deux).

Comment: Un amateur de logique, à la question _Tu veux du lait ou du sucre?_, répondra _oui_.

Comment: Ceux que j'ai vu faire ça était plutôt amateurs de farces que de logique.

Comment: @Joubarc: ... mais un francophone normal (tout le monde sait que les logiciens et les mathématiciens ne sont pas des humains à part entière) comprendra sans difficulté. Ce qui n'est pas le cas dans d'autres langues (japonais par exemple), où le défaut est pour un "ou exclusif" et ce type de question entraîne souvent un "oui", à la plus grande confusion des anglophones/francophones...

Comment: À propos des ambiguités parmi les et et les ou, moi qui fais de la logique linéaire, j'aimerais bien pouvoir exprimer facilement la différence entre « Est-ce qu'une tarte aux pommes ⊕ une charlotte aux poires conviendra ? » et « Est-ce qu'une tarte aux pommes & une charlotte aux poires conviendra ? » en français. (Contrairement à ce que l'on peut penser, les « ⊕ » et « & » sont tout les deux des *ou exclusifs*. Dans le premier cas l'interlocuteur n'aura pas le choix, alors que dans le deuxième il l'aura.)

Comment: J'ai un peu complété la question pour insister sur le cas où il y a plus de deux choix pour lequel je n'ai rien qui me convient réellement.

Comment: Entre informaticiens, on peut dire "oux" pour le exclusif, le "ou" étant par défaut inclusif ;)

Comment: Je préfère de loin dire _xou_ que _oux_.

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas, c'est encore un moyen d'insister sur qu'un ou est exclusif, ce qui n'est pas le sujet de la question et ne pose pas de problèmes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le français utilise normalement « ou » avec un sens inclusif (c'est-à-dire que plusieurs éléments coordonnés sont possibles simultanément) et « soit » ou « ou bien » pour marquer des ou exclusifs (c'est-à-dire qu'un seul des éléments est possible).

Mais quand les éléments sont naturellement optionnels, il est courant d'utiliser « et » pour le ou inclusif et « ou » pour le ou exclusif.  Un restaurant qui a une formule avec entrée et dessert permet trois plats, celui avec la formule avec entrée ou dessert n'en autorise que deux.  Mais ce n'est pas toujours le cas, si on vous demande si vous voulez du sucre ou du lait avec votre thé, vous pouvez prendre des deux.

À cause de cela, à cause aussi vraisemblablement des cas où les éléments sont naturellement exclusifs, un ou qui devrait normalement être considéré comme inclusif est parfois ressenti comme ambigu. Supprimer l'ambiguïté dans le sens du ou exclusif est facile, il suffit d'utiliser la formulation normale avec « soit » ou avec « ou bien ».  Pour la supprimer dans l'autre sens, on peut ajouter un « ou les deux » quand il n'y a que deux éléments, ou introduire la liste par une variation de « un ou plusieurs plats parmi ».

Comment: C'est malheureusement plus compliqué que ça. Par exemple les mathématiciens utilisent souvent « A donc P par le théorème S, ou bien B donc P par le théorème T » ou « soit A et alors P par le théorème S, soit B et alors P par le théorème T » pour démontrer P, même si A et B ne sont pas mutuellement exclusifs.

Comment: Pour moi dans cet usage on a le verbe être et non la conjonction. Voir 3 A 2 dans http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soit.

Comment: Non, c'est bien la conjonction (A et B sont des affirmations, pas des variables), et je t'assure que les mathématiciens rédigent souvent comme ça, alors qu'ils savent très bien ce que sont une disjonction inclusive ou exclusive.

Comment: Je m'étonne un peu du choix de la réponse acceptée…

Answer (score 10):

Une autre méthode pour lever l'ambiguïté: utiliser, par syllepse, un verbe au pluriel après la conjonction. Voir l'exemple trouvé sur [wikipédia:](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse#cite_ref-3)

> Dans « *Au moment où le Royaume-Uni, l'Espagne ou l'Irlande éprouvent la fin d'un cycle de croissance…* » rien n'oblige à mettre le verbe au pluriel avec la conjonction « ou », mais chaque nation ayant une situation similaire, c'est l'ensemble qui est pris en compte et l'emporte sur le choix d'une seule. **La conjonction n'est plus alors considérée comme alternative**.

En théorie<sup>1</sup>, ça voudrait dire que:

> Un fromage ou un dessert est compris dans le menu.

N'autorise qu'à choisir l'un des deux, mais que:

> Un fromage ou un dessert sont compris dans le menu.

Autorise à prendre un fromage **et** un dessert. Reste à trouver les restaurants imprudents…

Un [autre lien](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-71697.php) donne la même nuance:

> Quand 'ou' présente une alternative, soit l'un soit l'autre (pas les deux), le verbe sera au singulier.

Mais comme tu le dis, dans la plupart des cas le contexte seul devrait pouvoir déterminer l'intention.

Remplacer *ou* par *et* est aussi [mentionné](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-58658.php) comme un moyen de déterminer si un *ou* est inclusif ou pas — ce qui montre bien que ça peut aussi être un bon moyen de lever l'ambiguité, comme tu le signales déjà dans ta question (la réponse d'Evpok va dans le même sens).

Reste encore à signaler l'approche du « mathématicien fou » qui, s'interdisant d'utiliser *ou* directement, le contourne à coup de négations :

> Si vous prenez le menu, vous ne paierez ni le fromage ni le dessert.

Puisqu'il sait que `(a∨b) ⇔ ¬((¬a)∧(¬b))` et qu'il ne conçoit pas que quiconque l'ignore.

*<sup>1. Je ne suis pas convaincu non plus.</sup>*

Comment: +1, ne fut-ce que parce que tu es le premier à proposer quelque chose qui accentue, fut-ce faiblement, l'inclusion plutôt que l'exclusion.

Comment: Ha? Il me semlait que quelqu'un d'autree avait cité le très judicieux _ou les deux_: _Vous pouvez prendre un fromage, ou un dessert, ou les deux_.

Answer (score 10):

On peut indiquer une disjonction inclusive par « et/ou », mais c'est effectivement incongru, d'une part parce qu'il est inhabituel d'acoller deux mots ainsi, d'autre part parce que la [barre oblique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/472/utilisation-de-la-barre-oblique-slash-pour-une-alternative) n'est pas utilisée habituellement en typographie. L'expression « et/ou » est néanmoins relativement courante à l'écrit, en revanche je n'ai pas l'impression qu'elle se dise beaucoup à l'oral (`[e.u]` risque de ne pas être compris). On la trouve même dans des publications respectables telles que le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ou) :

> Que... ou (que) + subj. (sert à exprimer l'équivalence entre deux ou plusieurs suppositions différentes et/ou opposées, mais ayant la même conséquence exprimée par la proposition principale).

On peut lever l'ambiguïté en disant ou écrivant explicitement que la conjonction est permise :

> Il possède un chien, un chat **ou les deux**.
>   Je prendrai **au moins** un dessert ou un café.

Au hasard du web, je vois que [Druide informatique](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_22.html) avance que *et/ou* est venu de l'anglais (au départ juridique) *and/or* au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle. [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=et+ou&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) n'est d'aucune aide pour retracer l'histoire : les occurrences de « et/ou » sont noyées dans les numérisations erronnées de « et où » ou « et on ».

Comment: Au passage, une référence peut-être pertinente citée par le TLF : Mériz (D.). O. F. Imp(erative) + et/ou + imp. Two problems. In: [Mél. Solano (L.-F.)]. Chapel Hill, 1970, p.141.

Comment: À l'oral tout est question de prosodie et de gestuelle. Je pense qu'on peut très bien faire comprendre le sens du /e-u/ en levant la voix ou en faisant une petit pause entre les deux.

Answer (score 9):

Par défaut, je dirais que le *ou* français (comme anglais) est inclusif. Ton exemple ("fromage *ou* dessert") est souvent formaté d'une manière à mettre en avant la nature de "ou exclusif": en marquant une pause accentuée sur le "ou" à l'oral, en le *soulignant* (ou en l'*italicisant*) à l'écrit.

Comme tu le fais remarquer, il existe plusieurs formules visant à mettre en avant l'exclusivité (en plus de celles que tu listes, il y a aussi: "ou bien").

Par conséquent, je ne pense pas qu'il soit vraiment nécessaire de lever l'ambiguïté quand il s'agit d'un "ou inclusif" (c'est sous-entendu).

Comment: Je serais du même avis, mais malheureusement "ou" _peut_ avoir les deux significations: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ou et il peut toujours rester un doute.

Comment: @Joubarc: "peut", mais dans la pratique toute ambiguïté est résolue comme inclusive, je pense.

Comment: Je l'espère sincèrement.

Comment: @Dave, j'aimerais en être sûr.

Comment: Cela dit, il y [d'autres gens](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_22.html) qui voient les choses comme ça (à noter la mention de _oux_ que Sylvain avait proposé également).

Comment: Franchement, si l'on va considérer une horreur comme "oux" (OK: goût personnel mis à part, c'est surtout un terme que pratiquement personne ne comprendrait), autant passer directement à "et/ou" qui a certes ses nombreux détracteurs, mais me semble la seule vraie option dans les cas où la précision est vitale (et incontournable pour présenter trois options).

Answer (score 7):

Une façon d'indiquer qu'un *ou* est inclusif est de... l'omettre. Cette tournure fonctionne particulièrement bien avec les listes de plus de deux éléments.

Exemples :

> Je peux prendre le fromage, un dessert, un digestif.
>
> On y accueille les vieux, les malades, les sans-abris.

Comment: Mais si on ne mets pas de conjonction entre les deux derniers termes, on a l'impression que la liste est incomplète.

Answer (score 6):

La meilleure solution pour plus de trois éléments est à mon avis d'utiliser *et*, éventuellement en précisant qu'il n'y a pas d'obligation

> Vous pouvez prendre du fromage, un dessert et un digestif.

*Pouvoir prendre* pouvant être remplacé par *avoir droit à*, *pouvoir choisir*...

Ou, plus hasardeux

> Fromage ? Dessert ? Digestif ? Vous pouvez faire plusieurs choix.

Answer (score 5):

Le législateur français marque souvent le ou inclusif à l'aide de la lourde formule:

> Toute infraction est punie d'une amende et d'un emprisonnement ou de
>   l'une de ces deux peines seulement.

Comment: Cette formulation me semble mal s'étendre à trois cas ou plus.

Comment: Le poids de la formule tire cette réponse vers le bas.

Comment: C'est pourtant une information très pertinente.

Answer (score 3):

Je crois que le sens de *ou* (son « inclusivité ») dépend fortement du contexte. Dans une liste d'items à choisir, par exemple dans un menu de restaurant, il indique par tradition un choix exclusif. Dans la vie courante, il est à mon avis le plus souvent inclusif. Il peut par contre être rendu exclusif par une formule comme **« mais pas les deux »** :

> Vous avez assez de temps pour aller voir la tour Eiffel ou le musée d’Orsay, mais pas les deux.

Answer (score 2):

Tu indiques l'inclusivité de 'ou' avec tes indications nonverbales ou avec le contexte ou tous les deux.

Comment: Les indications non verbales ne passent pas à l'écrit. Sans compter que pour l'oral c'est comme pour l'écrit: j'insiste facilement sur le fait que c'est exclusif, pas que c'est inclusif (j'arrive à le faire, mais ça me semble toujours très lourd, « ou les deux » passe encore, mais je ne vois pas d'équivalent pour trois cas ou plus).  Me répondre que ne pas insister c'est équivalent à insister sur le fait que c'est inclusif me laisse une insatisfaction certaine.

Answer (score 1):

J'utilise souvent le *et/ou* bien que je le trouve « horrible » mais pas autant que la langue française quand elle est équivoque.

Ne pas proposer des outils d'expression simple et claire est une lacune que l'on doit bien combler d'une manière ou d'une autre quand on aime être précis et concis.

Answer (score 0):

Tout le monde ici semble penser que le «ou» français est par défaut inclusif, mais je trouve que c'est incorrect, ou plutôt incomplet.

Pour moi «ou» est généralement inclusif lors d'une affirmation, et généralement exclusif lors d'une question:
«Aimes-tu le chocolat ou la vanille?»
«J'aime le chocolat ou la vanille.»

Et quand on y pense c'est parfaitement logique (ou tout du moins pratique), en effet une affirmation  simple avec un «ou» exclusif ne serait pas très informative, le lecteur ne serait pas très avancé. («Bon alors, je sais que c'est soit l'un soit l'autre, mais lequel?»). Dans une question par contre il est plus informatif car il force l'interrogé a choisir ou à révéler qu'il aime les deux.

En somme l'utilisation et l'analyse tendent à chercher a maximiser l'information ( sauf si l'un des locuteurs est délibérément malhonnête et cherche précisément l'ambiguïté) .

Comment: "Aimes-tu le chocolat ou la vanille?" sonne vraiment bizarre. Je demanderais soit "Préfères-tu le chocolat ou la vanille?", soit "Aimes-tu le chocolat et la vanille?", selon le but de la question.

Answer (score 0):

Je propose d'introduire le néologisme *xou* pour marquer l'exclusion, à l'instar de l'anglais et de sa dénomination XOR pour la [fonction OU exclusive](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_OU_exclusif). Ainsi on garderait le *ou* dans son acception inclusive par défaut.

Answer (score -1):

Deux possibilités:

En utilisant "soit".

> Après le repas: soit du fromage, soit du dessert.

En utilisant une idée de préférence.

> Que préférez-vous, fromage ou dessert?

Comment: Ce sont des moyens de marquer clairement un _ou_ exclusif. Je cherche des moyens de marquer clairement les _ou_ inclusifs.

Comment: Désolé alors, j'ai compris la question à l'envers. au temps pour moi.

Comment: J'avoue qu'en survolant la question j'ai aussi cru que les deux sens de désambiguisation étaient demandés.