# La phrase « entre 1 et 10 », inclut-elle 1 ?

Tags: sens, nombres, intervalle

Si une devinette commence par « Choisissez un nombre entre 1 et 10 », est-il permis de choisir 1 ?

Est-ce que la réponse change dans un autre contexte ?

Par exemple :

> Pour garantir sécurité et fonctionnalité, la distance entre deux émetteurs doit être entre 1m et 10m.

Comment: Est-ce bien une question concernant la langue française ? La même question ne se pose-t-elle pas dans les mêmes termes et avec la même portée pour l'équivalent anglais *between 1 and 10* ?

Comment: La meme question se pose dans les autres langues, mais les reponses sont bien differentes. Ce type de distinctions sont traitees bien differement dans des differentes langues. (A comparer: Est 0 positif en francais/anglais/allemand? etc.)

Comment: @Romain: la question « Quels sont les nombres qui sont considérés positifs ? » se pose dans les mêmes termes en anglais, et la réponse est pourtant différente.

Comment: Wow, this is a real problem I have in France because these conventions are totally different in different languages and you want to close it as off-topic because you *think* that everyone else will use the same conventions (or, as the case may be, no conventions) as in France?

Comment: @Phira Look at the two question marks, I was just asking. And to close the question, just one close vote isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Stephane Les phrases *Is zero a positive number ?* et *Zéro est-il un nombre positif ?* ne se posent pas *dans les mêmes termes* si les mots *positif* et *positive* ont des références différentes donc des sens différents. Mais c'est donc bien une éventuelle différence de sens entre les mots *entre* et *between* qui nous intéresse ici, et en effet c'est alors une question légitime.

Comment: @Romain: La question de Phira est tout à fait légitime indépendamment de toute autre langue, et étant donné que tu admets toi-même que tu avais tort, je ne vois pas où tu veux en venir.

Answer (score 6):

Les limites sont généralement incluses dans l'intervalle ainsi défini. La formulation un peu lourde (utilisée principalement en math) pour les exclure serait : « Choisissez un nombre strictement compris entre 1 et 10. »

Answer (score 5):

**En règle générale, je comprends que les bornes sont incluses**, mais

Ça dépend essentiellement du contexte. Pour des distances entre 1 et 10 m, je dirais qu'il vaut mieux prendre une distance [prototypale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9orie_du_prototype), soit en gros 5 m, donc que 1 m soit inclus ou non n'a pas tellement d'intérêt.

S'il s'agissait d'un nombre d'objets, type « vous pouvez choisir entre deux et cinq caractères », je comprends que les deux et cinq sont inclus.

En tout cas, si il y a un risque de confusion, *deux inclus*, *cinq non inclus*, *deux ou plus*, *cinq ou moins* peuvent aider, un peu dans l'esprit de [Comment indiquer qu'un « ou » est inclusif?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/528/comment-indiquer-quun-ou-est-inclusif)

Answer (score 3):

Sauf indication contraire, je tendrais toujours à comprendre que les deux limites de l'intervalle sont incluses.

Answer (score 2):

Littéralement, si c'est entre, ce n'est pas sur les bornes, donc l'exclusion s'impose.

La devinette exige le choix parmi 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 et 9.

Mais souvent l'usage en fait à sa guise.

La bonne devinette : "choisir un nombre de 1 à 10", l'inclusion est entendue puisque l'on commence à un et que l'on s'arrête à dix, onze et zéro sont ignorés.

Le grotesque devient : l'installation du matériel sera valable à 1,0001 mètre jusqu'à 9,9999 mètres, et ne sera pas sécurisé de, 0 à 1 mètre et à partir de 10 mètres [pour un émetteur de taille 0,0001 m ?]

Dans la compréhension intuitive, il n'y a pas de bornes : le 1 de 1 mètre est l'origine d'un vecteur de 10 mètres indiquant une distance que l'on doit respecter par rapport à un point de référence.