# « Du … au … » inclusion ou exclusion ?

Tags: usage, nombres, indications-de-temps, intervalle

J'ai toujours remarqué que les gens utilisaient « inclus » en plus des dates dans le cas d'une fermeture exceptionnelle.

Par exemple :

> Fermeture du 8 au 12 Août inclus.

ou encore

> Fermeture du 8/08 inclus au 12/08 inclus.

Il me semble que normalement, la première date est incluse et la seconde ne l'est pas. C'est le jour de réouverture effective…

Ne faudrait-il pas donc toujours utiliser « *Fermeture du 8 au 12 Août* » tout simplement ?

Comment: Pas franchement un doublon, mais voir aussu ["entre 1 et 10" inclut-il 1?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/la-phrase-entre-1-et-10-inclut-elle-1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je ne pense malheureusement pas qu'il y ait de règle stricte en français. Chacun comprend cette phrase comme il le veut. (Le français n'est pas du [lojban](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban)).

Pour ma part, *Fermeture **du** 8 **au** 12 aout* est inclusif et *Fermeture **entre le** 8 **et le** 12 aout* est exclusif.

Le gérant du magasin précise pour qu'il n'y ait pas d’ambiguité. J'ai même déjà vu *fermeture du 8 au 12 aout, réouverture le 13*.

Answer (score 6):

L'utilisation de *inclus* permet juste de faire sauter l’ambiguïté sur le dernier jour. Ça a le mérite d'être clair ainsi.

Comment: Cela peut également être considéré comme une répétition ... ou un pléonasme.

Comment: Je suis d'accord mais l'essentiel est que les clients soient certains des heures d'ouverture, non ? Pour moi, c'est pour ça que c'est si souvent utilisé.

Comment: @Xaltar - Si _inclus_ n'est pas précisé, il se trouvera toujours quelques personnes pour poser la question. Risquer un pléonasme coûte moins cher que passer du temps à répondre au téléphone.