# Exclusivité du « ou » en français

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, coordination

Il me semble avoir entendu un jour parler de la non exclusivité du *ou* en français. De ce fait, le terme *et/ou* n'a aucun sens à partir du moment où le *ou* ne devient plus exclusif.

Quelqu'un pourrait confirmer cela (éventuellement en joignant un document officiel) ?

Comment: Cette assertion me semble tout droit extraite des [_Petites leçons de typographie_ de Jacques André](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/virginie.sans/BUR/docs/leconsTypo.pdf) (page 9).

Comment: Une question similaire: [Comment indiquer qu'un « ou » est inclusif?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/528/comment-indiquer-quun-ou-est-inclusif)

Answer (score 3):

L'emploi du *ou* peut être aussi bien *inclusif* qu'*exclusif*, tout dépend du contexte. Voir les références : [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjonction_de_coordination#Conjonction_.C2.AB_ou_.C2.BB) et [cntrl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ou)

Comment: D'où la présence du *et/ou* dans certains documents officiels. Etonnant qu'il n'y ai aucune règle explicite d'inclusivité ou d'exclusivité...

Answer (score 3):

La conjonction "et/ou" est issue de l'anglais "and/or".

Étant intrigué par votre question, je l'ai posée à l'Académie Française, voici la réponse de l'un de ses membres :

*La formule d'usage récent et /ou, calquée sur l'anglais and/or, signifie "l'un ou l'autre ou les deux" : Nous pourrons travailler ensemble lundi et/ou mardi = "lundi ou mardi, ou lundi et mardi".*

*En somme, chacune des deux conjonctions conserve son sens habituel, la barre oblique, correspondant au vel latin "ou, (si l'on veut...)", indique que l'on a le choix entre les deux. Certains ont proposé de substituer vel (qu'emploient déjà les locigiens) à et/ou, car malgré sa commodité, son caractère concis (économique), cette formule n'appartient qu'à la langue scientifique et technique, non littéraire.*

*Ou/et aurait le même sens, mais n'est pas usité.*